# Angularjs http get and C# api controller issues

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to use the get method of $http in angularjs. My selectedplayer is connected to a select and works properly. I also tried http.get with the same results. I get the first alert but nothing after. I have this(basically a copy of what our teacher did):

```
                $scope.selectedplayer;
                $scope.playerdata = [];                 
                $scope.getPlayerData = function () {
                    alert("function started");                   
                    return $http({
                        url: '/api/Player/' + $scope.selectedplayer,
                        method: "GET"})
                        .succes(function (data) {
                            alert("succes");
                            $scope.playerdata = data;

                        }


  ).error(function(data){alert("error")}                       
                );;
                alert("other");
            }
```

And my controller:

```
//GET: api/Player/Özil
        [Route("api/player/{playername}")]
        public Player Get(string playername)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            IEnumerable<Player> playerlist = db.Players.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(playername)).AsEnumerable();
            int cardcounter = playerlist.Count();
            int chance = 0;
            Random rng = new Random();
            if (cardcounter>1)
            {
                chance = rng.Next(0, cardcounter - 1);
            }
            return playerlist.ElementAtOrDefault(chance);

        }
```

If i reach it manually(eg http://localhost:63991/api/Player/Thiago) i get the results fine. I have a database that contains fifa ultimate team cards(their id,name and rating). A player can have multiple cards with different attributes. My aim is to select a player (let's say Özil) and get back one of his cards as a result.

Comment: Firstly, debug your issue properly - try with turning on browser console (F12 in chrome / ff) and looking at the request that is actually send to server.
Or You might try to store the URL you create into some local variable and print it to console to see whats in there. Bottom line - nail down the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to change your function to .success? This should help.

Comment: I just changed it to .then(function (succes){}) and it works now. Ty